# Safari failed to show the bg image in html page

Tags: css, safari, background-image

Today i faced an issue with Safari .In my website whrn i checked with Safari i found that the bg image given is not showing.The following is my code:
I tried many ways as per the forums ,but nothing is working for me.The other browsers are perfect.

```
<div class="post-holder wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-duration=".5s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration:.5s; animation-name: zoomIn;">
      <div class="post-img img-full" style="background: url( http://localhost/wivedit/theme/sw/images/sw_screen.jpg") bottom center no-repeat;></div>
            <div class="post-overlay" style="display: block; opacity: 0;">
                <div class="overlya-content">
                     <div class="tag" id="Sports">#Sports</div>
                    <div class="hash">#trump #uselection16</div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <span>Dozen </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="aurthor">By Panther </div>
                    <div class="stats">
                        <span>0 Likes</span>
                        <span>0 views</span>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

A css is related to the class :

```
.img-full {
background-position: 50% 50%!important;
min-height: 494px;
background-size: cover!important;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

How could i tackle this issue?

**Solved:** 
Edited the code:
*added a single quote' before and after the image path*

```
<div class="post-img img-full" style="background: url('http://localhost/wivedit/theme/sw/images/sw_screen.jpg') bottom center no-repeat;"> </div>
```

Comment: You have an error in the url for the background picture: there's a quote at the end. So according to the parser, that's where the `style` attribute ends. And then, mismatched parentheses. Solution: move the extraneous quote to where it belongs, after the `no-repeat;`

Comment: I changed the code as : <div class="post-img img-full" style="background: url( http://localhost/wivedit/theme/sw/images/sw_screen.jpg; ) bottom center no-repeat;">
                
                                  </div>